# ng build --prod - Error: Property body expected type of array but got null

Tags: build, angular-cli

I recently made a new branch in my angular project and am working on in for a bit. Now I wanted to build it for testing on smartphones. When using `ng build --prod`, I get the following error (`ng build` works tho!)

> An unhandled exception occurred:
> /Users/r/Documents/.../project/main-es2015.23a6f948094203a25f4a.js:
> Property body expected type of array but got null See
> "/private/var/folders/c5/y_n4tj316sq9x1nqx20qdlh40000gp/T/ng-FBFvv4/angular-errors.log"
> for further details.

The angular-errors.log is not helpfull at all:

> [error] TypeError:
> /Users/r/Documents/.../project/main-es2015.23a6f948094203a25f4a.js:
> Property body expected type of array but got null
> at validate (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:160:13)
> at Object.validate (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:229:7)
> at validateField (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:24:9)
> at Object.validate (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:3)
> at NodePath._replaceWith (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:172:7)
> at NodePath._remove (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/removal.js:57:10)
> at NodePath.remove (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/removal.js:36:8)
> at PluginPass.ForOfStatement (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-for-of/lib/index.js:206:16)
> at newFn (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:175:21)
> at NodePath._call (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
> at NodePath.call (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
> at NodePath.visit (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:92:31)
> at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:116:16)
> at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:88:19)
> at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
> at Function.traverse.node (/Users/r/Documents/.../project/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:82:17)

Production Environment.prod.ts looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  VERSION: require('../../package.json').version
};
```

I tried using the `--source-map=true` flag, but it is canceling building before its able to write the sourcemap.

I didnt put hands on my `package.json` since two month, but also tried deleting the `node_modules` and reinstall them.

I also tried changing `rxjs` and `typescript` versions, but no success

Im using angular -v 10.1.6, typescript -v 4.0.3, rxjs -v 6.4.5
What can I do??

Any help appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16998.

My problem was using [Labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). It appears that babel is having a bug with that.